# Italian translation in a multi-language site don't work

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, multisite

I've a multilanguage site in Magento 1.9. I set Italian like default language.
There are some words in the footer that aren't translate. I added this words into csv file but the problem remains.
It's shown in the following image:
[image]

"QUICK LINKS", for example, remains in English language. I Found this string in only in the file page.xml and I try to change it but it isn't changed. The code part of this file where I found this string is the following:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
                </block>
                <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
                <!--<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
                </block>-->
            </block>
```

Can you help me, please?
Thank's!

Comment: add your footer file code here

Comment: ok, I edited my question!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to let English the default language and use in line translations so that every single is word is translated.
Keep Italian as a different store.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change text in xml file with your default language.

add also `translate="title"` in xml like below

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
```